# Repair of Office Professional did not complete successfully

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

When I try and run Repair on my installation of Office Professional Plus 2010 I get the error

> Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 configuration did not complete
>   successfully. The file {90140000-01
>   15-040g-0000-0000000FF1CE)-C\OfficeMUI.msi could not be found.

Word, Excel, Outlook, Access all work properly, I have no complaints. The problem only came to light when trying [failing to install Sharepoint Designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/sharepointdesigner-encountered-an-error-during-setup).

How do I fix this?

The host is 64bit Windows 7 Professional.
Office is 32bit.

**update:** discovered there is a logfile in `%tmp%` which contains a more information. The complete file, `SetupExe(2012100316390915A0).log`, is [here](http://pastebin.com/EwXVS2Pr). And the relevant portion seems to be:

```
Running OSE version 14.0.4730.1010
LIS: start caching package "{90140000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}"
LIS: creating download package "{90140000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C"
LIS: finished starting caching package "{90140000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}"
PERF: TickCount=192496326 Name=Completed verify local install source Description=End function
Error: File "C:\MSOCache\All Users\{90140000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C\OfficeMUI.msi" cannot be found for MSI install Type: 20::FileNotFound.
```

And indeed the file does not exist (and neither does "C:\MSOCache" for that matter).

Comment: @karan, I rolled back the edit as the first rendition was correct. There is no colon (:) in C\OfficeMUL.msi

Comment: NP, but the file name was wrong initially (MUI, not MUL, as MUI stands for Multilingual User Interface). Also, not to nitpick, but are you sure the GUID has a { before and a ) after it?

Comment: @mattwilkie some days ago, I had exactly this problem and the only way to fix this problem was uninstalling and reinstalling that. please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago, I had exactly this problem and the only way to fix this problem was uninstalling and reinstalling Office.

To uninstall Office, [use FixIt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-Windows-computer-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> Click [Fix it](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9815935).
>
> At the bottom of your screen, click Open.
>
> [image]
>
> **NOTE:** If the file doesn’t open, click Save > Open Folder, then double-click the file (it should start with "O15CTRRemove") to run the Fix it tool.

Comment: Except that this question is not about uninstalling Office.

Comment: @slhck some days ago, I had exactly this problem and the only way to fix this problem was uninstalling and reinstalling that.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Hopefully this helps someone. I don't have this computer or situation anymore so can't evaluate or rate your answer in context of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Reboot and close all non-essential apps, including any running minimised in the tray/notification area
2. Go to **%TMP%** (type in the Start Menu search box or Run dialog accessed via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
3. Delete all files (skip any that you're not allowed to or that are in use); you can also use something like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) for this
4. *Move* the **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft Help** folder somewhere else, say to the Desktop
5. *Move* the **%AllUsersProfile%\Microsoft Help** folder as well (obviously don't mix the two folders up, in case they need to be restored to their original locations)
6. Retry the repair or better still the install
7. If it works you can get rid of the **Microsoft Help** folders you backed up

Comment: didn't work, sorry. There are 3 files in %tmp% which are in use and can't be deleted:`etilqs_eQpMkSnOdq6IHqg, FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt, GoogleQuickSearchBox.log`. ProcessExplorer tells me they are owned by Firefox, Spoolsv.exe, and the last is obvious.

Comment: You did *move* the Help folders elsewhere, right? Were there any .LCK files inside them?

Comment: I renamed them to start with `xx`. There were no .lck files. I quite firefox and tried again. This time I noticed a folder created in %tmp% called `Setup000015a0` and a file `SetupExe(2012100316390915A0).log`. Reading the latter shows a more complete error message, namely `Error: File "C:\MSOCache\All Users\{90140000-0115-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C\OfficeMUI.msi" cannot be found for MSI install Type: 20::FileNotFound.`. There's more, which I'm about to add to the question.

Comment: @mattwilkie: If you haven't managed to solve this yet, the only other possible solutions that might work AFAIK are running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated Command Prompt, or doing a repair install of the OS itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following commands/Methods to repiared it

1. Right Click & Open With...changed file association
2. Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations
3. Repaired MS Office from Control Panel
4. Finally the method which work was : Wright down the command (winword.exe /r) in the Start Menu -> Run. If you don't find run in start menu, right click on Taskbar & Start Menu Property -> Go to second Tab(Starat Menu) -> Click on Customize -> Enable check Box (put Tic mark) > Ok -> Ok.

Then you will get Run command in Start Menu

Answer (score 0):

to romove microsoft word 2010 plus after unsuccesful installation.. Go to the system retore point. It will show the installed programs depending on the days you installed that programme.

For instance you are just from installing Microsoft office and the setup was unsuccessful

click on it and click on the next icon to run system restore

the Microsoft word software will be removed And you have to start the installation again

it worked for me

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question, which ask how to fix an unsuccessfull repair not install.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Open task manager.

Go to background processes

Close Microsoft bootstrapper

Run office again and see if configuration works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on a Windows 10 64-bit machine running Office Pro 2007:

1) Open a command prompt as an Administrator (CTRL-ESC, type CMD, right-click on the Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator).
2) Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /r
   (include the quotes)

The location of your Office files will depend on the version you're running.

Comment: Does this run the repair?